# Iterating in a list and deleting contents of an object in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, reflection

I have an **Arraylist named deleteFields**.
I have an **Object named mergedDiffSRO**.
I have to delete all the fields of **mergedDiffSRO** which are present in **deleteFields**.

```
LeadDetailsSRO mergedDiffSRO = new LeadDetailsSRO();

    public class LeadDetailsSRO{
        private String      emailId;
        private String      emailByCompany;
        private int         level;
        private LeadObjects leadobj;
        private String      alternateNumber;
        private String      languagePreference;
        private String      kycName;
        private String      businessAs;
        private String      aadharName;
        private String      panName;
        private String      ovdName;
        private String      kycStatus;
        private String      aadhaarStatus;
        private String      panStatus;
        private Set<String> ownershipTypeSet;
        private String      empId;
        private String      designation;
        private Boolean     nameMatchSuccess = null;
        private String      isSIMandatory;
    }


    List<String> deleteFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    deleteFields.add("businessAs");
    deleteFields.add("empId");
    deleteFields.add("designation");
    deleteFields.add("emailByCompany");
    deleteFields.add("level");
    deleteFields.add("ovdName");
```

How do i proceed with the same?
Is reflection to be used for the same?
Please suggest some way out with proper code in **JAVA**.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and/or some code showing how the array list and the object are defined.

Comment: Can you please show us something more? I.e. an example code that you have tried so far. Also, example inputs and expected outputs would be useful.

Comment: @joakim  : I have no idea on how to proceed and haven't tried anything yet!

Comment: @tamas : the sample input for this function would be the same, mergedDiffSRO object and the arraylist deleteFields.The expected output is an object of the same class as mergedDiffSRO with those fields not in the object which are present there in the field

Comment: @ankur43 please, try something and show us what you have. We can't proceed without code samples.

Comment: @tamas edits done

Comment: @joakim edits done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with reflection. But that's ugly, slow and error-prone. So, here it is:

```
public void deleteFieldsByName(LeadDetailsSRO details, List<String> fieldNames) throws Exception {
    for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
        Field field = LeadDetailsSRO.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

        // this is usually not allowed at production settings
        field.setAccessible(true);


        Class fieldType = field.getType();

        // the following if-else is ugly.
        // But that's what we can do. We have to differentiate by classes.
        if (fieldType.equals(String.class)) {
            field.set(details, null);
        } else if (fieldType.equals(Set.class)) {
            field.set(details, new HashSet<>());
        } else if (fieldType.toString().equals("int")) {
            field.set(details, 0);
        }
    }
```

I suggest that you look for other kind of solutions.

#### Update

We can do it without reflection too. This is still ugly and error-prone. But at least, it's fast and it will work in prod environments too:

```
public class LeadDetailsSRO {
    private String emailId;
    private String emailByCompany;
    private int level;
    private String alternateNumber;
    private String languagePreference;
    private String kycName;
    private String businessAs;
    private String aadharName;
    private String panName;
    private String ovdName;
    private String kycStatus;
    private String aadhaarStatus;
    private String panStatus;
    private Set<String> ownershipTypeSet;
    private String empId;
    private String designation;
    private Boolean nameMatchSuccess = null;
    private String isSIMandatory;

    public void deleteFields(List<String> fields) {
        for (String fieldName : fields) {
            switch (fieldName) {
            case "emailId":
                this.emailId = null;
                break;
            case "emailByCompany":
                this.emailByCompany = null;
                break;
            // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to handle cases like that of 
private LeadObjects leadobj;
Please do suggest a check for the same!